# Why isn't localStorage accepting my object?

Tags: javascript, object

I need to store an object like the one I the example below in `localstorage`. I need to be able to retrieve this object and edit it, then save it back into `localStorage` for next time.

```
var data = {lastEdit:"September", expires:"December", records:[{arrives: "12:45", departs: "12:51"}, {arrives: "13:03", departs: "13:04"}]};
```

I tried this but it said 'undefined':

```
localStorage.setItem("dataStore1", data);
var output = localStorage.getItem("dataStore1");
```

What can I do to fix it?

### Solved

Comment: `localStorage` accepts only strings as data, use `JSON.stringify` on your data before passing it to localstorage

Comment: FYI `localStorage` is not part of JavaScript. It's an API standard implemented by browsers, not a language feature.

Comment: All done, thanks for your assistance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `JSON.stringify()` to set `JSON` and `JSON.parse()` to convert `JSON` to a JavaScript object; `localStorage` expects a string to be set.

Comment: Ah, ok. I'll just try that.

Comment: That worked - thanks! I'll accept your answer when it lets me

Answer (score 4):

From [Using the Web Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API):

> *"Storage objects are simple key-value stores, similar to objects, but they stay intact through page loads.  The keys and **the values are always strings** (note that integer keys will be automatically converted to strings, just like what objects do)."*

You cannot store a complex `Object` value in localStorage. Sorry.

Instead, you should serialize your Object as a string [hint: [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)] and then after retrieving it parse from JSON string back to Object [hint: [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)].

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that for me - much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

`localstorage` is limited to string key/value pairs use `JSON.stringify()` before storing it and `JSON.parse()` after retrieving it.

```
var testObject = { 'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3 };

// Put the object into storage
localStorage.setItem('testObject', JSON.stringify(testObject));

// Retrieve the object from storage
var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('testObject');

console.log('retrievedObject: ', JSON.parse(retrievedObject));
```

Comment: While your answer is correct, it isn't saying anything that the other two answers that were here well before yours don't already say.